# Get data from span tag android jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I want to get an image bloger avatar from URL example:  https://soundcloud.com/topsify

```
<span style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000132054558-5ra8gl-t500x500.jpg&quot;); width: 200px; height: 200px; opacity: 1;" class="sc-artwork sc-artwork-placeholder-8 image__rounded image__full g-opacity-transition" aria-label="Topsify’s avatar" aria-role="img"></span>
```

I try to get:

```
document = Jsoup.connect("https://soundcloud.com/topsify").get();
Elements imgElement = document.select("span[style*=background-image:]");
```

But it return empty. 
Please support to get avatar url: https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000132054558-5ra8gl-t500x500.jpg
Thanks !

Comment: What is image avatar? Do you mean the favicon of the URL?

Comment: It will be better, if you mention your input code, not url

Comment: Sorry i can't post image link:
<span style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000132054558-5ra8gl-t500x500.jpg&quot;); width: 200px; height: 200px; opacity: 1;" class="sc-artwork sc-artwork-placeholder-8 image__rounded image__full g-opacity-transition" aria-label="Topsify’s avatar" aria-role="img"></span>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `userAgent` String. Following code is just example, you can use `element.select()`.

Check the view source of the page. It is **img** tag, not **span** tag `<img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000132054558-5ra8gl-t500x500.jpg">`

```
    String url = "https://soundcloud.com/topsify";
    Response res = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko").timeout(3000).execute();
    Document document = res.parse();
    //get <img> tags
    for (Element img : document.getElementsByTag("img")) {
    Elements avatars;
    //get src attribute value whose has "avatars"
    if((avatars = img.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("src", "avatars")) !=null){
     System.out.println(avatars.attr("src"));
    }             
 }
```

Comment: Log.d(TAG, "elements " + getImageURL(imgElement.toString()));
Also return empty !!

Comment: @Lucas I checked your avatar url and updated answer.